# How to express surprise in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

In English language, we can use OMG "oh my God" to express surprise.

> OMG, I lost the movie ticket!

I am just curious  if we can use same expression in Spanish context.

for example:

> Oh mi Dios, he perdido el boleto del cine.

Does it make sense? Or is there any other better similar expression in Spanish?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Oh mi dios", es poco común al hablar pero se está volviendo frecuente en algunas películas y series mal dobladas.

Solemos decir cosas como "¡Dios mío!", "¡Oh, por dios!", "¡Ay dios!", "¡Dios!".

Answer (score 7):

Destacar que en España no se utiliza la palabra "boleto", ni "ticket" para referirse a una entrada de cine.

Lo correcto sería "He perdido la entrada del cine".

Tampoco hay una traducción exacta a " Oh my god", si bien podría usarse "¡Vaya!", por ejemplo.

---

Quick english response:

In Spain, Europe, we don't use "boleto" if you are talking about a ticket movie. You have to use "entrada" instead. The literal translation to OMG will be "Oh dios mío", but it's not a common expression if you want to express surprise for example. It's a more natural expression use "¡Vaya!", for example.

Comment: -1 I don't think that is a good translation for what the OP meant. `He perdido la entrada del cine` doesn't express surprise. It is just stating a fact. So the tone is completely wrong in relation to the context.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why you say first "¡Vaya!" to express that surprise. Anyway, you can make a fact a way more surprising by your tone, that's up to you.

Comment: I think *vaya* is a bit mild as a surprise expression. It's just *meh*. I guess the answer is rather **incomplete**. There is no definitive suggestion for how to express surprise in this context.

Comment: No, there isn't. For this case the surprise comes by your tone. "Vaya" maybe isn't the more expressive word, and in the real world you will use "Mierda" (shit), "Joder" (fuck) or so.

Comment: Then we agree to disagree. In latin america we would never use vaya to express surprise. So most of the spanish world would never use it here.

Answer (score 6):

Dependerá mucho del país:

- México:

  > ¡No manches!, perdí el boleto de la película.

Comment: Invito a los demás a que editen la respuesta añadiendo sus países y expresiones.

Comment: Pasa la invitación a la pregunta así la leeran más personas ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In Spain we sometimes use the expression `hala`

> ¡Hala! Mira, una limusina (o un perro verde)!

["Hala"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=mJNhFMfNxDXX2rzcdsyF)

This expression can be used to other means, like [hurrying somebody](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=y4tWrhpTiD6aaYp7Ht)

> Hala, vete vistiendo que llegamos tarde

Other expressions on top of my head would be:

- Anda: `Anda, he perdido el billete de lotería`
- Ahí va: `Ahí va, he perdido el billete de lotería`

Please, note that these two are [pronounced in a very different way from how they are written](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/ahi-va-o-ay-va-14795/)

- caramba
- jolines (a really mild form of swearing)
- Mi madre
- La virgen
- ¡Rayos! (a really mild form of swearing)

Comment: "Ostras", "mierda", "mecachis", "me cago en..." o, desenterrando tebeos, icluso "recórcholis", "cáspitas"

Comment: "ostras" se me ocurrió luego, camino a casa (bueno, de hecho, "ostris"). Otros como "mierda", "mecachis", "me cago en..." expresan más enfado que sorpresa, pero sí, todos se podrían añadir a la lista.

Answer (score 3):

Al menos en Cuba es poco común encontrar personas que digan:

> Oh mi dios, he perdido el ticket de la movie.

Más bien encontrarás personas que digan:

1. ¡Oh dios mío! He perdido el ticket de la película.
2. ¡Dios mío! He perdido el ticket de la película.

Answer (score 2):

Lo más cercano es la siguiente expresión:

> ¡Dios mío! Perdí el boleto para la película.

Comment: No entiendo por qué alguien votó en contra de esta respuesta.

Comment: Esta es la única forma en que podrías escuchar "OMG" en Chile, aunque curiosamente se usa muy poco. Lo normal es que se usen palabrotas, que no vienen al caso aquí como respuesta, como "chucha", "por la cresta", "mierda", etc.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Rodrigo and others that expressed that we use cursing words instead of "Oh! Dios", or "Vaya".

What none mentioned is that sometimes there are not really 'bad words' but they mean them.(Just like 'sugar' or 'arse'). Usually kids use some of them, or when a bad word is not appropriated (say, job meetings). These are some expressions used in Bolivia.
Examples:

"Miércoles" (Wednesday) instead of "mierda"

"Mier... mosa patria" - "Mi hermosa patria" (my beautiful country) starts sounding like "mierda"

"Caraj...teres" instead or "carajo"

"Ajo!" (garlic) or "Ajos y cebollas!"(garlics and onions) sounds close to "carajo!"